# Kotlin Opt-in: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler

Tags: android, kotlin

I followed the Kotlin documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html#module-wide-opt-in) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#experimental-status-of-unsigned-integers) to opt into `kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes` for the whole module. My module `build.gradle` looks like this now:

```
android {

    ...

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes"
    }
```

Lint is still complaining about ExperimentalUnsignedTypes and when compiling I get this warning:

```
> Task :myModule:compileDebugKotlin
w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
```

My kotlin version is: 1.3.61

Comment: Try with `-Xuse-experimental=...`

Comment: awesome... that worked. Where did you find that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html)

> `@RequireOptIn` and `@OptIn` annotations were introduced in 1.3.70 to replace previously used `@Experimental` and `@UseExperimental`; at the same time, `-Xopt-in` compiler option replaced `-Xuse-experimental`.

`@OptIn(...::class)` and use of `-Xopt-in=...` were introduced in Kotlin 1.3.70, but the old and gold `-Xuse-experimental` is still available in future versions (tested in Kotlin 1.4-M1).

Comment: With latest Kotlin you will see this warning: `Argument -Xopt-in is deprecated. Please use -opt-in instead`